# Prestashop buy via email

Tags: prestashop

i want to ask. Is it possible to disable all payment method's and buy product via email? I mean when user click buy in cart page, he need to enter email and confirm order without payment and then admin get notification about order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with the development of a custom payment module.

Regards